# Existence of random variables with certain properties

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, moments

Can there exist two random variables such that -

1) Their means are not equal.

2) Their k-th order raw moments for all k>1 are equal.

Comment: Relevant wikipedia: [Hamburger moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem)

Comment: Hint: the difference of the distribution measures will be orthogonal to $x^k$ for $k=0,2,3,4,\ldots$. Can that be possible when each of the measures is bounded (by $1$)?